# ELK (Elastic Stack) Visualization of running processes of a server

Tags: elastic-stack, kibana-4, elk, metricbeat

I am monitoring an application with MetricBeat only. Everything works fine. But I have no idea, how I can show running processes at a specific time (or period of time) with Kibana Visualization. I need to now, which processes have been started upon a request, how long they where running and how much resources they consumed. I was thinking about line. But I have no idea how to configure. Any ideas?

Comment: Nobody has an idea? Is the description to short?

Comment: Did you solve that issue? Do you run Kibana on a Ubuntu or *ix server so that you may use tools like `htop`?